# Securing read/write for documents in one to one relation of client to document reads/writes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I have a firebase project containing a few read and write APIs built with cloud functions that will be consumed by many different clients/websites without the need for authentication. However, I want them to access ONLY "their own" documents in firestore. Firestore model looks like following:

```
- companies
  - company1
  - company2
  - company3
  - etc...
```

Each company should only be able to read/write to its own company-document and not be able to tamper with any of the other documents. The tricky part for me is to understand how I can from a security perspective make each website consuming this API only and ONLY read/write to the document_id that is specified (currently specified as pathParam). Here's an example of it:
`/companies/${document_id}/bookings`

As this stands, it's very easy for company1 to tamper with the document of company2 just by looking up company2's website and grabbing the document_id from the request. What possible solutions are there to make this kind of communication secure with firebase? Only thing i can think of is public/private key cryptography between requests, but i don't have enough knowledge yet to decide if that would be a good solution or if there are any better solutions out there. Appreciate any answers, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input Jose! Been working on a solution for the last few days and I think I have a decent one in place soon. I did indeed use Firebase auth, specifically **authenticating with email-link**, meaning no password required. This will be perfect for my case. I also use **custom claims** where i add custom claim for each company representing the document_id to be updated. This is done in a tiny **cloud-function** made on the backend for each company. This way im not sending any document_id visibly via http but rather this document_id will be passed within a jwt-token. I can then retrieve that claim in my backend-service from the token to update the correct document_id. Not saying this is completely safe since one can switch tokens from one site to another and send it via http and make a valid POST to wrong document_id. The effort of doing this is quite large and the damage/impact is rather small, so the chances for someone trying to tamper with data is at least largely reduced. And it feels way better in my stomach this way :D

Answer (score 0):

Firestore provides [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), which can be used to restrict access to certain documents within collections based on a condition. However, you need to combine this with [Firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), and Firebase auth is aimed to authenticate users rather than apps.

Thus, for what you want to achieve, you would need to implement a user auth mechanism, which I understand it's not what you want.

There are no other Firebase provided ways of securing Firestore data that I know of. I believe you will need to implement something yourself in order to achieve what you want. Indeed, as you mentioned, a Public/private key system could do the trick.